# In the Firebase Rules how to test if a node exist elsewhere before allowing `.write`

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The write access to `STREET_ID` is allowed if a `STREET_ADDRESS`  has an id that is the "-K1234567"

Firebase Rule json:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "$countries": {
      "STREET_ID": {
         ".read": "auth != null",
         "$PathKey": {
           ".write": "root.child('US/STREET_ADDRESS').hasChild(-K1234567)",
           ".validate": "newData.isString()"
         }
       },
       "STREET_ADDRESS": {
           ".read": "auth != null",
           ".write": "!data.exists()"
       },
  }
}
```

Firebase json:

```
  "UA": {
    "name": "Ukraine"
  },
  "AE": {
    "name": "United Arab Emirates"
  },
  "GB": {
    "name": "United Kingdom",
      "STREET_ID": {......    
  },
  "US": {
    "name": "United States",
      "STREET_ID": {
         "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3138 E Maple Ave": "-K1234567",
         "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3139 E Maple Ave": "-K12334rt"
        },
        "STREET_ADDRESS": {
          "-K1234567": {
              "path": "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3138 E Maple Ave",
              "values": {
                "call": false,
                "id": "",
                "start_date": "",
                "end_date": "",
                "type": "",
                "name": ""
              }
          }, 
            .............
        },
```

As you see the "-K1234567" is a Push key in `STREET_ADDRESS` and a value in `STREET_ID`, Basically user can only insert a `STREET_ID` if the id exist in the `STREET_ADDRESS`.

I read about the [newData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#newdata) and try to apply it like this:

```
 ".write": "root.child('US/STREET_ADDRESS').hasChild(newData.val())",
```

That don´t work or should it?? 
How can I make this work?

Comment: Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: ok good, must check for other errors then, thanks